# Change the scrollbar styles in KendoUI grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to change the scrollbar css in Kendo UI grid. [image]

Is there any way (jQuery or CSS or anything) to change the styles. I wanna **change the width** of the **scrollbar**.

Comment: Just FYI, the default scrollbar is determined by the browser and has nothing to do with kendo styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In webkit, you can use `::-webkit-scrollbar` property to define custom scrolbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #ccc
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: #888
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #eee
}
```

OR

you could use Javascript plugins  to customize scrollbars, like [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/nested_scrollbars_demo.html)

Comment: Glad to help, have a look at mentioned plugin jQuery custom content scroller. you can do better :)